# Process and ProcessBuilder

Tags: java, bash, scala, awk

I'm trying to run a process that greps free memory, but the process builder fails to parse the awk portion ...

```
scala> import scala.sys.process._

scala> "grep MemFree /proc/meminfo" #| "awk '{print $2}'" !
awk: cmd. line:1: '{print
awk: cmd. line:1: ^ invalid char ''' in expression
res16: Int = 1
```

Same results with this ...

```
scala> Seq("grep", "MemFree /proc/meminfo") #| Seq("awk", "'", "{print $2}", "'") !
awk: cmd. line:1: '
awk: cmd. line:1: ^ invalid char ''' in expression
```

Escaping doesn't work either ...

```
scala> Seq("grep", "MemFree /proc/meminfo") #| Seq("awk", "\"'{print $2}'\"") ! 
res21: Int = 0
```

How can I get awk '{print $2}' to work?  Is there a way to examine what the process builder is trying to execute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The apostrophes are only used by the bash to know where the boundaries of arguments are. In Scala, when you use a `Seq`, these boundaries are given and the apostrophe has no meaning, they are passed to `awk` which then complains.

```scala
import scala.sys.process._

(Seq("grep", "MemFree", "/proc/meminfo") #| Seq("awk", "{print $2}")).!
```

Also note that the arguments for grep must be separated.

---

By the way, if you want to get the value into Scala, you can use `!!`:

```scala
(Seq("grep","MemFree","/proc/meminfo") #| Seq("awk","{print $2}")).!!.trim.toInt
```

Answer (score 0):

The pair of `'` is used in Bash or similar shells to indicate that spaces within are *not* delimiters for separate arguments.  That is `'{print $2}'` means that the first argument to the `awk` command should be the string `{print $2}`.

So you're looking for `Seq("awk", "{print $2}")`.